# How to print a multimap that has the elements sets

Tags: c++, stl, set, multimap

I'm using a multimap of the following structure:

```
typedef std::pair <set <int> , char> trigger;
std::multimap <trigger , set <int> > transitions;
```

to simulate the transition function of a deterministic finite automata, so that from a set of states it goes by reading a symbol to another set of states.
How do i print this multimap?
I tried it like this:

```
for (std::multimap<trigger,set<int> >::iterator it=transitions.begin(); it!=transitions.end(); ++it)
    {
    for (std::set<int>::iterator its=it.first.first.begin(); its!=it.first.first.end(); ++its)
    std::cout << *its<<" ";
    std::cout<<(*it).first.second<<endl;
    for (std::set<int>::iterator its=it.second.begin(); its!=it.second.end(); ++its)
    std::cout << *its<<" ";
    }
```

But it says that the multimap has no member named first or second.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with these lines

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator its=it.first.first.begin(); its!=it.first.first.end(); ++its)

for (std::set<int>::iterator its=it.second.begin(); its!=it.second.end(); ++its)
```

is that it is an iterator. Use -> access its value.

```
for (std::set<int>::iterator its=it->first.first.begin(); its!=it->first.first.end(); ++its)

for (std::set<int>::iterator its=it->second.begin(); its!=it->second.end(); ++its)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
its=it.first.first.begin();
```

Note you have a

```
std::multimap <trigger , set <int> >
```

The issue is that `it.first` is pointing to a *set*, which has no "first" nor concept of first.

Comment: How do i access the elements of the sets then?

Comment: I have some trouble understanding it. Don't i use first to acces the first element of the pair of the multiset and then another first to access the first element of trigger? I know that i should print the set by using iterators but i don't know on which object to apply begin.